# Function to get all prime numbers up to n

Tags: javascript

I have tried to solve it but I don't know where to start. Can I have some help?

`primeNumberFromOneToN` function receives 1 argument 'n' the function returns the prime numbers from 1 to n?

```
function primeNumbersFromOneToN(n) {
  // (I need the code with explanation please)
}
```

Comment: Hi iyal, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please show the attempt that you mentioned you tried? It will help with giving us a starting point and help us show you where you went wrong.

Comment: Hey i didnt know how to start i tried searching but no luck so i need someone to help me understand how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function primeNumbersFromOneToN(n) {

  let primes = [];

  // We start checking from 2 and check all numbers up to n
  for (let check = 2; check <= n; check++) {
    let include = true; // Prepare to include

    for (let i = 2; i <= check / 2; i++) {
      // We try to divide by each number from 2 to half of the number we are checking, if it is evenly divisible by any of these, it is prime
      if (check % i === 0) {
        // If the remainder of this modulo operation is 0, then it is evenly divisible
        include = false;
      }
    }

    // If include is still true, we include the number
    if (include) {
      primes.push(check);
    }
  }
  
  console.log(`Number of primes from 1 to ${n}: ${primes.length}`);
  return primes;
}

console.log(primeNumbersFromOneToN(777));
```